# Fetch: Why is my content-type changing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, fetch, react-redux

This is kind of two questions in one. I'm pretty solid in Rails but a noob at react/redux and I'm struggling with implementing authentication on the react/redux app.

I have a Rails 4 API that I've built. It's well tested and solid. My Rails API is using the devise-token-auth gem.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/sign_in', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': "application/vnd.myproject.v1"},
  body: {email: email, password: password},
  ... // snip response handling
})
```

And yet, when it sends a request, my API returns a `401 Unauthorized` and the request fails.

Checking out the server log, the body I sent for the request isn't showing up.

```
params: {"format"=>"json", "controller"=>"devise_token_auth/sessions", "action"=>"create"}
```

Taking a look at the request in the Network view of my browser, I see the `sign_in` request with the following:

```
accept:application/vnd.myproject.v1
content-type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
```

I see that the content-type is now `text/plain`. (Interesting that "accept" is lowercase... I wonder about that too.)

Can someone explain to me what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send X-CSRF-TOKEN with your post requests or you should skip verify_authenticity_token

If you want to skip authenticity_token verification, you can use something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request?

  protected

  def json_request?
    request.format.json?
  end
end
```

If you want to set header, see example jQuery Ajax request:

```
              $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'script',
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',
                                $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
                        }, url: $(ui.item).closest('.sortable').data("sortable-link"),
                        success: function (data) {
                            ....
                        }
                    });
```